# Mongodb db.runCommand debugging

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 applications that are using listCollections to get infomation. Both are going through the C client but they are using different versions. In my Mongodb output I can see they are running slighly different statements on the server :-

> 2019-09-22T04:24:31.707+0000 I COMMAND  [conn9] command datalake.$cmd command: listCollections { listCollections: 1, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "test" } numYields:0 reslen:333 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 0ms
>
> 2019-09-22T04:26:34.183+0000 I COMMAND  [conn12] command datalake.$cmd command: listCollections { listCollections: 1.0, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "test" } numYields:0 reslen:333 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 0ms

The one difference I can see between the two is that one is passing in **listCollections: 1.0** and the other passes in **listCollections: 1**.

Is there any way I can convert the log output above into a db.runCommand() that I can execute to see if I get different results ?

Answer (score 1):

> The one difference I can see between the two is that one is passing in **listCollections: 1.0** and the other passes in **listCollections: 1**.

The value parameter for the [`listCollections` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections/) is irrelevant -- it exists to create a key/value pair when constructing a BSON document to pass as a parameter to `runCommand` but isn't used by `listCollections`.

All of the following are equivalent (although a numeric value makes more semantic sense):

```
db.runCommand({'listCollections': 1})
db.runCommand({'listCollections': 1.0})
db.runCommand({'listCollections': 'foo'})
```

If you are using MongoDB 4.0+, the document format can be useful to provide additional optional fields like `filter` and `nameOnly`.

Instead of passing a document as the first parameter for `runCommand()` in the shell, you can also just use provide the command name to run with the default options:

```
db.runCommand('listCollections')
```

> Is there any way I can convert the log output above into a db.runCommand() that I can execute to see if I get different results ?

Equivalent commands in the `mongo` shell to your log output would be:

```
use datalake
db.getMongo().setReadPref('secondaryPreferred')
db.runCommand({'listCollections': 1})
db.runCommand({'listCollections': 1.0})
```

The `listCollections` queries will be processed identically. However, since you are using the `secondaryPreferred` read preference it is possible that this query might be returned from different members of your replica set when your two applications are running queries concurrently. Normally this will not be an issue, but if your use case requires strong consistency you should use a `primary` read preference instead.